# C# SQL: get sql connection try attempt

Tags: sql, timeout, database-connection, sqlexception

I am trying to get the number of the try attempt of a SQLConnection to inform the user about those attempts.
Below you can see the code, where magic should happen. 'i' would be the number of the attempt. The connection 'con' throws a lot of SqlExceptions, but i can't catch them like shown below. 'databaseConnection' represents the connectionstring. It is currently empty for testing purposes.
I bet, that i am missing something, but I can't figure out what, since I'm new to SQL programming in C#.
"txtProgressbarWorking" is a label in the UI.

```
                int i = 1;
                con = new SqlConnection(databaseConnection);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                catch(SqlException s)
                {
                    txtProgressbarWorking.Content = "Connecting... " + (++i);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with this code:

1) Are you calling this in some sort of loop? If not, your `i` variable won't be incremented.

2) `SqlConnection.Open()` throws several kinds of exceptions - not just `SqlException`, which I assume is why you "can't catch them" all as you mentioned. You should ideally specify each exception or catch the higher-level `System.SystemException`.

3) Your code to increment the progress bar is in the catch-block of your exception handler, and will only be executed if the exception is caught. If you are in fact calling this code in a loop, you would want to move the code in the catch-block into the try-block instead.

4) Your `++i` should be `i++` so that `i` is incremented after the statement; either that, or initialize `i` to zero instead of 1. The way you have it now, the first value from `i` in your catch-block would be 2.

I suggest you take a look at [MSDN's documentation on SqlConnection.Open Method ()][1]
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open%28v=vs.110%29.aspx